# Facing an error while running my code in the index.js file

Tags: javascript, sanity

```
8:28:08 pm [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "part:@sanity/base/schema-creator" from "schemas\index.js". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/schemas/index.js:1:27
  1  |  import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator';
     |                            ^
  2  |  
  3  |  import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type';
      at formatError (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41235:46)
      at TransformContext.error (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41231:19)
      at normalizeUrl (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39540:33)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39673:47)
      at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:41506:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Users/ferna/Desktop/Pixel/Pixel_backend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-5e7f419b.js:39313:29) (x2)
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Try to write a title that both summarizes your question, but also helps to distinguish your question from other similar questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to import these files.

```
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type';
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator';
```

What you need to do at this point is to import your own created schema into schema.js and add it to the array of types. Open schemas/index.js and do the following:

```
// schemas/index.js
import pet from './pet'

export const schemaTypes = [pet]
```